# How do we derive the interior of a set in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$A=\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1 < x_1\ + x_2 <2\}$

The interior to this is the same set but this is what we can say by simply observing it. Is there a way to derive it?

Comment: An open set is equal to its interior. Prove that this set is open by showing that there is an open neighborhood around any element of $A$ that is a subset of $A$.

Comment: You can prove this set as open by definition. $\forall x \in A\  \exists \  r>0\  s.t \ B(x,r)\subset A$

Comment: $A$ is the preimage of the open set $(1,2)$ under the continuous map $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1+x_2$, and hence is open. As the interior of a set is the union of all open sets contained within it, it follows that $A=A^\circ$.

Comment: Adding to @Math1000 's comment, we usually say in such a case that the set is *defined by an open condition*.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I have not heard that terminology before, but a Google search found it come up in a few books. Interesting.